# Frame or texture when using openGL effects in camera2

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

who can tell me what is the best and optimal way when using OpenGL effects in camera2 ? 
1. using a frame
or
2. a texture

Comment: What effects?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: f.e. bokeh, postal, paster.. These effects are done on camera, now i want to add those on camera2 and looking for sufficient fast way